# Conversion error when converting 'nvarchar' to 'datetime' in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nvarchar, datetime-conversion

I have this code :

```
DECLARE @StartDate nvarchar
SET @StartDate='22/10/2014'
SELECT CAST (@StartDate as datetime)
```

And it gives me this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can anyone suggest a better way/at least no error way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the string which represents to date in format `dd/mm/yyyy` you can use this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate nvarchar(10)
SET @StartDate='22/10/2014'     
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate, 103)
```

Declaring `varchar` means setting the length to 1.

Comment: Now it gives the error: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: But @Hamlet Hakobyan in my case '22/10/2014' is coming from database. I mean it is a column value where it is being saved like this.I think is there anyway to convert '22/10/2014' to '20141022' ? Then that will work.

Comment: That works man. One small thing can you help me in finding the month from this I mean in the string form like 'jan' not '01'

Answer (score 5):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on `CAST` and `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible