# Convert varchar column to datetime in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a table with following definition and data.

**Definition:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTB]
(
    [CREATEDATE] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Data:**

```
 10/9/2014 
 1/26/2015 
 2/16/2015
```

When I run the query:

```
Select 
    CAST(CREATEDATE AS DATETIME) as CREATEDATE 
FROM 
    [dbo].[TestTB]
```

It is throwing error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The above does not work even after running

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
```

However the following query works fine

```
  DECLARE @data nvarchar(50)
  SET @data =  ' 10/9/2014 '
  Select CAST(@data as DateTime)
```

Above query returns: 2014-10-09 00:00:00.000

How do I convert a date string (of mm/dd/yyyy format) stored in a column to datetime?

Comment: Use `convert()`:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx.

Comment: Why do you store them as varchar at all? Don't do that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Tried Select CONVERT(DATETIME, CREATEDATE, 110) FROM [dbo].[TestTB]. Same error.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Inherited a legacy DB

Comment: @user2520246: so it's not possible to change it? You will save a lot of time in future, so i would take the breaking change. Your queries will also be much more efficient with the right datatype and you can't run into localization issues.

Comment: `SET DATEFORMAT dmy` would not be correct if your data has date strings like `2/16/2015`

Comment: @user2520246 Shouldn't it be `CONVERT(DATETIME, CREATEDATE, 101)` - 101 instead of 110?

Comment: is the format of CREATEDATE consistent through all rows?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697936/conversion-error-when-converting-nvarchar-to-datetime-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if your table column is "DateTime" type than it will save data in this format "2014-10-09 00:00:00.000" no matter you convert it to date or not. But if not so and if you have SQL Server version 2008 or above than you can use this,

```
DECLARE @data nvarchar(50)
SET @data =  '10/9/2014'

IF(ISDATE(@data)>0)
BEGIN
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @data)
END
```

Otherwise

```
DECLARE @data nvarchar(50)
SET @data =  '10/9/2014'

IF(ISDATE(@data)>0)
BEGIN
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @data)
END
```

### To Insert into table

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
SELECT CREATEDATE FROM
(
    SELECT
        (CASE WHEN (ISDATE(@data) > 0) THEN CONVERT(DATE, CREATEDATE) 
        ELSE CONVERT(DATE, '01/01/1900') END) as CREATEDATE 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[TestTB]
) AS Temp
WHERE
    CREATEDATE <> CONVERT(DATE, '01/01/1900')
```

Comment: Appreciate your help.But my problem is how do i query this against a table column.I just want to query the table column containing the date string, convert it to a datetime value and update the date in a datetime column of the same table.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @data nvarchar(50)
  SET @data =  ' 10/9/2014 '
  SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @data, 101)

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CREATEDATE, 101) as CREATEDATE 
FROM [dbo].[TestTB]
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2103

please check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yes this works as i have mentioned in question.How do i do conversion when the date string is stored in a varchar column?

Comment: Appreciate your help. However SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CREATEDATE, 103) as CREATEDATE 
FROM [dbo].[TestTB] retuns the same error.

Comment: got the problem 103 was for dd/mm/yyyy but your data is in mm/dd/yyy format. 101 is correct. now check it @user2520246

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
SELECT IIF(ISDATE(CREATEDATE) = 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CREATEDATE, 110), CREATEDATE) as DT_CreateDate
FROM [dbo].[TestTB]
```

[SQL Fiddle Solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5b56e/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

nvarchar to datetime is an implicit conversion, it means you can do this:

```
declare @strDate nvarchar(50), @myDate datetime
set @strDate = '01/26/2013'
set @myDate = @strDate
```

But your problem is date format so you have to convert it, but you have to scpecify the format or style and the code of the style you're using is 101 (according to [this table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)) so the secure way:

```
 declare @strDate nvarchar(50), @myDate datetime
 set @strDate = '01/26/2013'
 set @myDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, @strDate, 101)
```

You can skip the code but with diferent configuration(server) that code will break.
If you use the ISO style (yyyymmdd) you never would'nt have to worry and the conversion would be implicit:

```
  declare @strDate nvarchar(50), @myDate datetime
  set @strDate = '20150421' --ISO style (yyyymmdd)
  set @myDate = @strDate
```